# Trying to understand and get classes to work for p5.js

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, p5.js

I am trying to learn how to use classes to make my code reusable. I have began by trying to create a background class which should, when the draw method is called, generate a background, however at present this does not happen. Please can I get feedback on the class and any mistakes I have made using it.

Using online resources I have tried to set up a background class based on a function, as shown in the code. I am using the online p5.js editor to code, found here:https://editor.p5js.org

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 700);
  const a = new treeBackground(1,1)

}

function draw() {
  a.draw()
}

class treeBackground {

  constructor(bg, diam) {
    this.bg = bg;
    this.diam = diam;
  }

  draw() {
    this.bg = createGraphics(width, height);
    this.bg.beginShape();
    this.bg.noStroke();
    for (this.diam = 1.5 * width; this.diam > 0.5 * width; this.diam -= 20) {
        bg.fill(map(this.diam, 0.5 * width, 1.5 * width, 255, 210));
        bg.ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, this.diam, this.diam);
    }
    this.bg.endShape();

  }

}
```

No errors should occur and a canvas with a grey background should be shown in the sketch area.

Comment: Your variable 'a' is in a block scope inside the function 'setup' which means the 'draw' function can't access that variable. Move the declaration of 'a' outside of the 'setup' function so that you can access it globally.

Comment: Does this code work? What happens when you run this? If you're asking for feedback on your code, you should check out [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things going on:

- As saucel noted, since `a` is referred to in various places, it needs to be defined in a shared scope (e.g. like a global variable).
- Also `bg` is should be `this.bg` in `draw`. It should also be initialized only once, so it probably should be moved to the constructor. It looks like the passed arguments `diam` and `bg` aren't actually used, so they should be removed.
- `beginShape` and `endShape` are used for making shapes in conjunction with the `vertex`, `curveVertex`, `bezierVertex`, and `quadraticVertex` functions. Since you're not doing that here, they're not necessary.
- Finally createGraphics creates an offscreen renderer. To actually show it on screen, you can use the `image` function.

All together, it looks like this:

```js
var a;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 700);
  a = new treeBackground();
}

function draw() {
  a.draw();
}

class treeBackground {

  constructor() {
    this.bg = createGraphics(width, height);
  }

  draw() {
    this.bg.noStroke();
    for (this.diam = 1.5 * width; this.diam > 0.5 * width; this.diam -= 20) {
        this.bg.fill(map(this.diam, 0.5 * width, 1.5 * width, 255, 110)); // changed this to make the gradient more pronounced
        this.bg.ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, this.diam, this.diam);
    }
    image(this.bg, 0, 0);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/p5@0.7.2/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```